# joining 2 table with mutiple column sum in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to joining 2 table from MYSQL in PHP With SUM. But when I get result it shows multiply result. I don't know what's wrong in my script. Please help. My script shown bellow with table:

```
   Table1: purchase
   id      model       quantity     retquantity   
   1        D54          10            NULL
   2        D54         NULL            5
   3        M90          10            NULL
   4        M95          10            NULL
   5        M90           5

  Table2: sale

  id      model       quantity      retquantity
   1        D54          5            NULL
   2        D54         NULL            5
   3        M90         NULL            5
   4        M95           6            NULL
   5        M90          10            Null
```

My php script:

```
    <?php
        $count=0;
        $sql = "SELECT purchase.model,sale.model, 
    SUM(purchase.quantity) AS pquantity,SUM(sale.quantity) AS squantity,
    SUM(purchase.retquantity) AS retpquantity,
     SUM(sale.retquantity) AS sretquantity
    FROM (select model,
    sum(quantity) AS pquantity,sum(retquantity) AS retpquantity from 
     purchase group by model)purchase
    INNER JOIN (select model,
     sum(quantity) AS squantity,
    sum(retquantity) AS retsquantity
     from sale group by model)sale
     ON purchase.model=sale.model
    GROUP BY purchase.model,sale.model";

    $result = $cn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    ?>
    <td><?php echo ++$count; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['model']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['pquantity']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['squantity']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['retpquantity']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['retsquantity']; ?></td>

                    <?php }} $cn->close();?>
```

I dont get any result. Please Help.

Comment: where is your mysql query??

Comment: you get errors or anything...

Comment: first print your query what you are executing to clear the query validity, also share your query..

Comment: this is the query  $sql = SELECT purchase.model,sal.........

Comment: I am getting this error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query may this helps

```
SELECT id, SUM(model) as model, SUM(quantity) as quantity, SUM(retquantity) as retquantity FROM (
       SELECT * FROM purchase
       UNION ALL
       SELECT * FROM sale
       UNION ALL
       ) AS somealias GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object